# How to configure url-pattern under security domain in web.xml from java at runtime?

Tags: java, spring, jboss, web.xml

I have security domain configured in `web.xml` as:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>all</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>all</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>${param-name</url-pattern>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
            <http-method>PATCH</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Now I want to set url-pattern here at server startup from java at runtime. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

refer [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html) to set url-pattern